# How do I know which function to substitute the variable when solving problems by the "Integration by substitution" method?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, substitution

In Calculus, we use the "Integration by Substitution method" to integrate variables that are otherwise difficult to do by the conventional method. What I don't understand  which function do we have to take as a substitute. Is there perhaps a different/faster way to integrate functions by a simple  method which will help solve functions quickly?

Can anyone please help me on this topic?

Comment: Integration is hard precisely because there's no quick do it all method. However for definite integrals you may refer to [differentiation under the integral sign](https://www.cantorsparadise.com/richard-feynmans-integral-trick-e7afae85e25c) as a powerful technique to have under your belt, and usually integrating by parts also may be use to find antiderivatives

Comment: @LourencoEntrudo . I would add (for the benefit of the proposer) that integration often produces new kinds of functions. E.g. integrating the rational function 1/x (for x>0) gives ln(x) but ln(x) cannot be expressed as a combination of rational functions and inverses of rational functions.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet good point. There are even functions that don't possess an antiderivative

Comment: @DanielWainfleet@Lourenco Entrudo I know that integration has no quick do it all method. The below explanations have given me the clarity i needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You normally substitute the function which satisfies the given condition:

$u=f(x)$

$du=f'(x)dx$

In this way you simplify the integrand to  only $f(u)du$, and if you get some constant in front, you simply place them outside the integral sign.

One example is this:

$\int \sqrt{x}e^{ix}dx$

Here we take advantage of that x and its square root are related to one another by the square. So here we substitute $u^2=x \rightarrow u=\sqrt{x}$. Then $du=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}dx$ .

So we get: $dx=2\sqrt{x}du$. Here you see that $\sqrt{x}$ already exists in the integrand, so that is included for expressing *dx* in form of *du*. You then get:

$2\int e^{iu^2}du$

Here you can use the Error function integral to solve it, while if you tried to solve the first integral using integration by parts, you would end up in a infinite cycle of integration and differentiation of the parts of the integral.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent question.

You usually want to substitute which has properties which can with the pre-substituted expression lead to a more simpler expression.

With an Example:

Let's take the following example:

$$ \int \sqrt{1-x^2} dx$$

If I substitute $x=\sin u$, replacing $dx = \cos u du $, then I have:

$$ \int \sqrt{1-\sin^2 u } \cos u du$$

Now, $\sqrt{1-\sin^2 u } = \cos u$ by Trigonometric laws. **This is the point here, we got a new simplification for this expression which wouldn't have been there if we only considered the original expression**. Continuing:

$$ \int \cos^2 u du $$

If you know your trigonometric identities, then:

$$ \frac{\cos 2 u+1}{2} = \cos^2 u$$

We can substitute that in the integral and it would turn our problem into just integrating a $\cos 2u$ and $1$, which are things we already know to integrate.